# Is there any way to use "withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)" with default image by not adding any tint colour of a button?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use "withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)" to set an image on a button, but don't want to change any tint colour. Just want to set the default image.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
let image = UIImage(named: "image_name")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Here I didn't want to use red tint colour. But if though I didn't use any tint colour, I didn't get actual image. I just want to set actual image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is already colored the way you like, then you could leave off the

`withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)`

From documentation, Apple states that UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate will:

> Always draw the image as a template image, ignoring its color information.

Also, to ensure you get your original color you could use:

`withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)`

Back to the documentation:

> Always draw the original image, without treating it as a template.