# Why using withRenderingMode is required when assigning UIImage to UIImageView/ UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift

When I came across most of the examples, I notice almost all of them are using `withRenderingMode`, when assigning an `UIImage` to `UIImageView`, `UIButton`, ...

Examples are :-

[Action Sheet with Image for each option on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817569/action-sheet-with-image-for-each-option-on-ios)

[Is there any way to use "withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)" with default image by not adding any tint colour of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193919/is-there-any-way-to-use-withrenderingmode-alwaystemplate-with-default-image)

My initial thoughts is that, the purpose of using `withRenderingMode`, is to generate a new instance of `UIImage`, so that changing the tint color of an UI component, will not affect rest of others.

I wrote a simple program without using `withRenderingMode`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView3: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let chooseImage = UIImage(systemName: "photo")
        
        imageView1.image = chooseImage
        
        imageView2.image = chooseImage
        
        imageView3.image = chooseImage
        
        imageView1.tintColor = .red
        
        imageView2.tintColor = .green
    }
```

I expect all `UIImageView` will end up of having same image color, but it doesn't happen.

[image]

Can anyone show an example, on when using `withRenderingMode` is really necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WithRenderingMode doesn't change the image at all or make a new image.  It just sets how the image will appear when used in a UIImageView.  The docs say "The rendering mode controls how UIKit uses color information to display an image" and the idea of a rendering mode was created because in iOS 7 there was this new visual style where images and text in the "tint color" of the app are considered to be tap-able buttons. And often you want an image to be like this, a 'template' image, and be rendered in the `tintColor` of the UIView that it's in.  The alpha channel (transparency) is used for background, anything not alpha is foreground, if the rendering mode is `.alwaysTemplate`